# Is origin/CONTRIBUTING.adoc updated for 4.x codebase?

Tags: okd

I'm trying to follow the CONTRIBUTING.adoc steps to get my dev env set up (for the first time). But this `hack/env hack/build-base-images.sh` is erroring out on me. If I `git checkout release-3.11`, the script finishes, and I can `make release` as well. But with 4.1 or 4.2 codebase, it immediately spits out;

```
[openshift/origin-source] open /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/images/source/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
[WARNING] Retrying image build for openshift/origin-source:latest, attempt 1...
[openshift/origin-source] open /go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/images/source/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
[ERROR] hack/build-base-images.sh:56: `return "${result}"` exited with status 1.
```

I'm on RHEL 7.6 with docker 1.13 and go 1.13. Is the doc updated for 4.x codebase, and thus it should "just work," or something must be wrong with my RHEL server?

https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-4.2/CONTRIBUTING.adoc